# Having issue with NSURLConnection

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection

I have single view for both uploading and downloading images and audio files. Here what I am doing

To start downloading i am using this :

```
 NSURLConnection *theConnection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
```

and this trigger its delagate methods

```
connection:didReceiveResponse:

connection:didReceiveData:

connectionDidFinishLoading:
```

and in these methods I am calculating file size, showing downloading progress through progress bar and saving files in my device.

For uploading I am doing this

```
[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

and using this `connection:didSendBodyData:totalBytesWritten:totalBytesExpectedToWrite:`

this delegate methods works fine upload file and also tells about bytesWritten, totalBytesWritten, totalBytesExpectedToWrite but it also calls

```
connection:didReceiveResponse:

connection:didReceiveData:

connectionDidFinishLoading:
```

and its valid because all are delegate methods.

But problem is I am using these three to handle downloading.

What is the correct way to work with NSURLConection regarding uploading and downloading data?

Reference [Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001836-BAJEAIEE)

Comment: I will give you a more detailed answer later.

Answer (score 2):

The best way for me would be to implement the delegates in dedicated classes (e.g DownloadingDelegate and UploadingDelegate) and instantiate different delegates for each connection. The download and upload process could then be handled totally independently.

Or, if the download and upload are not concurrent, it can be simpler to use a boolean as a flag and test it in your delegates functions.

For example, let say you use a boolean instance variable called `downloading`.

You will have for the download:

```
downloading = true;
NSURLConnection *theConnection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
```

And the upload:

```
downloading = false;
[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

Then in your delegate:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    if( downloading )
    {
        // handle the response when downloading ...
    }
    else
    {
        // when uploading
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Save the pointers to the NSURLConnections and inside the delegates determine which one is used.

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    if(connection==downloaderConn) {
       //handle download
    }
    else {
       //handle upoad
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for reply, this was in my mind, but is this a correct approach?

Comment: for simpler cases, where it wouldnt make sense to have to dedicated class it does. apple uses it extensively in there samples. Just remember that while this approach is good with 2 or 3 classes, it gets messy with N connection objects

Answer (score -1):

You can Use `AFNetworking` for your task.

`AFNetworking` is a delightful networking library for `iOS` and `Mac OS X`. It's built on top of `NSURLConnection`, `NSOperation`, and other familiar `Foundation technologies`. It has a `modular architecture` with well-designed, feature-rich APIs that are a joy to use.

Find the [SDK here](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking)

Comment: @JackyBoy ,i Just guided Him a alternate way which might be helpful for him.is that incorrect ?

Comment: The person is not asking for an alternative way of doing X or Y, but for an explanation of how to do X and Y. `AFNetworking` abstracts a lot of tasks, which, in this case, doesn't help answering the question.

Comment: Why @SweetJenny is not using the approach told by siba as it's good way.

Comment: I think use AFNetworking will be very easy way and you have not to do lot of coding task as those are already did by that sdk.

Comment: Must have understanding and grip of basics. Not just using frameworks every time. In complex situations and tight deadlines when you dont have grip on basics its a really a nightmare.